# Configure Android Studio Module to use Google APIs

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, gradle, android-studio

I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure the modules of my Android Studio project to use the Google APIs instead of the standard Android ones. I have several modules that (for the most part) successfully imported from a former eclipse project.

To illustrate what I mean, you can see in the below image that the project build target is configured for the Google APIs instead of, for example, Android 4.4.2

[image]

This is causing a problem on the following import (as well as others)

[image]

I'm sure someone here has had a similar issue. I've searched several times but can't seem to find a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this problem, the solution is to open your project structure and in the Compile SDK Version field put "**Google Inc.:Google APIs:19**" replacing 19 with the version you want to compile with.